# Booting grub-2.00 with 2 initrds, crashes with RAMDISK: incomplete write

Tags: grub2, initrd

So, I'm trying to split my initrd into two initrd's. There's some pretty significant scripts that run in the initrd, and we wanted to split the initrd so we could rev the just the logic or just the kernel portion.

As a single initrd, it boots fine. But, when I split it into two, I get an error:

```
RAMDISK: incomplete write (-28 != 8388608)
```

The grub menu entry's initrd looks like:

```
initrd /initramfs-scripts.img /initramfs-kernel.img
```

I can't find any documentation on using two initrd's. All I have found so far are [this: stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39307/slitaz-4-0-grub2-loopback-concatenate-multiple-initrd-images), and [this: grub bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?35238). But, it doesn't give me an idea about what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: could it be that the -scripts.img and kernel.img should be in opposite order?

Comment: I don't see why. It was my understanding, that the two images get extracted one after the other, and then run. And their files don't overlap. The kernel one is just /lib/modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a complete answer, but there's some weird behavior with pygrub and initramfs's. It seems to append a few bytes to the end. The bytes are zeroed, so cpio wouldn't care about them. However, we encrypt the initramfs, so the decryption algorithm does.